# Why bottom border line of textField is showing half?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, border-layout

I have 5 textFields in my UIViewController and I have to show bottom border line on these all textFields.

I am using `FloatLabelTextField` class and trying to set bottom border on each textField by programatically but very first time (in viewDidLoad method) border line is just showing half. I don't know why this is showing.

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UITableViewController {

    @IBOutlet var vwName: FloatLabelTextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        vwName.delegate = self
        setBottomBorder(textField: vwName, width: 0.8, color: .darkGray)
    }
}

extension ViewController : UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        if let sublayers = textField.layer.sublayers {
            for layer: CALayer in sublayers  {
                if layer.name == "BottomBorder" {
                    layer.removeFromSuperlayer()
                }
            }
        }
        setBottomBorder(textField: textField, width: 0.8, color: .blue)
    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        if let sublayers = textField.layer.sublayers {
            for layer: CALayer in sublayers  {
                if layer.name == "BottomBorder" {
                    layer.removeFromSuperlayer()
                }
            }
        }
        setBottomBorder(textField: textField, width: 0.8, color: .lightGray)
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }
}

extension ViewController {
    func setBottomBorder(textField: UITextField, width: CGFloat, color: UIColor) {
        let border = CALayer()
        border.name = "BottomBorder"
        border.borderColor = color.cgColor
        border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: textField.frame.size.height - width, width: textField.frame.size.width, height: width)
        border.borderWidth = width
        textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.none
        textField.layer.addSublayer(border)
        textField.layer.masksToBounds = true
    }
}
```

If I tap on a text field then border line is coming properly. I mean when `TextFieldDidBeginEditing` delegate method call then border line showing properly.

But initially when view load then it is showing half.

Comment: Initially try to set border in viewDidLayoutSubviews method.

Comment: Implement viewDidLayoutSubviews() and give Proper width you want

                border.borderWidth = width
                textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.None
                textField.layer.addSublayer(border)
                textField.layer.masksToBounds = true

Comment: But viewDidLayoutSubviews() is getting called continuously so only gray colour is showing.

Comment: Please help. Thanks

Comment: The reason they are asking you to move where you set the border is because viewDidLoad() is too soon for many things that depend on the frame size. You can also try two other places (both of which are before ViewDidLayoutSubviews(): viewWillAppear() and viewWillLayoutSubviews(). (I'm pretty sure the latter will also be called more than once. If any of these work, **but** calling more than once is an issue, set up a flag to have your code only execute things once.

Comment: I wrote the same code in loadView()  it's working. @dfd

Comment: What should I do is it correct ?

Comment: There is no such method as loadView(). Please correct your error. That would help me to answer your latest question. Thanks.

Comment: @dfd you are right. There is no such method as loadView().
So in ViewDidLayoutSubviews() method I can set the flag and only one time I can run ?

Thanks

Comment: Sure. I say if it works, just force it to do what you need it to - one time, whatever. Some things you just have to go with what the OS gives you!

Comment: OK Thanks @dfd I will.